# What is `record.introduction` and `record.teaser` in bolt ?

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I was just going through the listings.twig file and came across the following lines of code:

```
<h2><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></h2>
{% if record.introduction %}
    {{ record.introduction }}
{% elseif record.teaser %}
    {{ record.teaser }}
{% else %}
    <p>{{ record.excerpt(300, false, search|default('')) }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Now what exactly is `record.introduction` and `record.teaser` ? I understand the last `else` part , but i don't quite understand the `if` and `elseif` part. Can somebody explain what `record.introduction` and `record.teaser` really is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are two fields in your ContentType. They are defined in `app/config/contenttypes.yml`.

Your pasted code checks if the introduction field is available or has content, if not, it will try the teaser field.